# Sending SMS using car horn

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, telecommunication

If you've been watching Bones series, there is an episode in which Bones and Hodgins were trapped beneath the ground, and they managed to send an SMS by wiring the phone to the car honk. Is this possible? What is the exact mechanism used?

I'd appreciate it if someone points out if the question is in the wrong site.

https://vimeo.com/210057258

Comment: Why did they have to do that in the show? Was there something wrong with the phone?

Comment: The phone was disassembled.

Comment: You asked: "I'd appreciate it if someone points out if the question is in the wrong site."  And to answer - Engineering really isn't about solving unrealistic situations that script writers come up with.  Not a good fit for the site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the clip you gave (which I glossed over the first time), I think they needed to power the phone so they wired into the circuit that draws power from the car battery for the car horn. That circuit doesn't require the car to be on in any way so that would be the reason to use that circuit.